# vue3 Warning on responsive object

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Reactive Map contains both the raw and reactive versions of the same object as keys, which can lead to inconsistencies. Avoid differentiating between the raw and reactive versions of an object and only use the reactive version if possible.

I created a dialogVisible ref object to control whether the dialog is displayed or hidden, and the warning occurs when I assign a value to dialogVisible

this here dialogVisible.value = true

```
  dialogVisible.value = true
  dialogTitle.value = t('action.' + type)
  formType.value = type
  resetForm()
  // 
  if (id) {
    formLoading.value = true
    try {
      formData.value = await ContractApi.getContractDetail(id)
    } finally {
      formLoading.value = false
    }
  }
}
defineExpose({ open })
```

Comment: seems the issue may be in code you haven't shown - sure, the first line "triggers" the warning, but, the warning suggests you may be doing something wrong somewhere else

Comment: Yes, I also think so, but I can't find any place where the problem occurred. Here, I have defined an open function. It is precisely the code I provided that I used xxxxref. value. open() in the parent component to trigger a pop-up window. This warning only appears when the open function is triggered. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I found the problem and it appears in the dictionary I am using, with a key value of NAN

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and it appears in the dictionary I am using, with a key value of NAN